# How does one find out the cv error from the sklearn package?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to plot a learning curve to figure out whether my model is suffering from high bias, and to achieve this I would need to plot the training set errors versus the cross validation set errors. In `Scikit Learn` is there a way to get this information?

`rscv_rfc = grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), param_grid, n_jobs=4, cv=10)`

`rscv_rfc` gives me the best estimator etc., alongwith the best params for the model. Is there a way to receive the mean cv error from this object?

Answer (score 1):

The docstring of `RandomizedSearchCV` tells us that it exposes `grid_scores_` containing all the scores it evaluated. However, these are all scores evaluated on held out data from splits of the training set.

[Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.15.X/sklearn/grid_search.py#L375) is the place where the scores are actually evaluated. While the function `_fit_and_score` actually has an option `return_train_scores`, which you could set if you constructed your own grid search object, it is set to `False` here and thus the training scores remain unaccessible.

I am wondering whether it would be useful in general to have this option propagate through into the `*SearchCV` objects or not.